Plotting failure (simple differentiation)
I want to get the plot of differentiate as follows.
But something is wrong and empty plot came out.
Could tell me how to correct the code?
rosinRammler[x_, D_, n_] := 1 - Exp[-(x/D)^n]

(below: Differentiate with respect to x )
 dFdx[x_, D_, n_] := D[rosinRammler[x, D, n], x]

(Plot the derivative for D=1 and n=2)
 Plot[dFdx[x, 1, 2], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Derivative of Rosin-Rammler Distribution", AxesLabel -> {"Particle Size (x)", "dF/dx"}, PlotStyle -> Blue]


Do not use D for variable and You can't differential w.r.t. to a number. This fixes these two issues.
rosinRammler[x_, d_, n_] := 1 - Exp[-(x/d)^n]
dFdx[x_, at_, d_, n_] := D[rosinRammler[x, d, n], x] /. x -> at 
p=Plot[dFdx[x, at, 1, 2], {at, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Derivative of Rosin-Rammler Distribution", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Particle Size (x)", "dF/dx"}, PlotStyle -> Blue]



I want to get the data of the above

data = Cases[p, Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]]


ListPlot[data]


 ListLinePlot[data]



Thank you very much! It is very useful!! I could get the plot I exactly wanted. And, if it doesn't bother you, may I ask the other question? I want to get the data of the above, such as {{0,0},{0.20,0.383}, {0.77,0.851},{2.00,0.073},{3.00,0}}. But dFdx[x, at, 1, 2], {at, 0, 5} doesn't give me the numerical data...

@rani fyi, updated.

Oh, thank you SO MUCH!!! It's so nice of you!
